# How to define case classes with members with unbound type parameters?

Tags: scala, generics, type-inference, case-class

Given a class definition with bound type parameter `Animal[A <: String]` it seems that the Scala compiler does not infer `B <: String` from `Animal[B]`. Is the inference allowed? How to help the compiler to do the inference?

Below is a concrete example with case classes where the lack of this inference is a problem.

Consider the following case class hierarchy:

```
sealed trait Person[+T <: Person[T]]
case class Student() extends Person[Student]
case class Professor() extends Person[Professor]
```

I need to define a case class `University` which I can instantiate with a variable of type `Person[_]`, for example `val p: Person[_] = Student()`. I thought this would work with the following definition:

```
case class University(p: Person[_])
```

But this fails compiling with the error:

```
type arguments [Any] do not conform to trait Person's type parameter bounds [+T <: Person[T]]
```

If I bind the type parameter of the case class `University` it compiles (it also compiles with unbounded parameters if i drop the `case` keyword but this is not an option in my case):

```
case class BoundUniversity[P <: Person[P]](p: Person[P])
```

But this parametrized version cannot be instantiated with an unbounded variable of type `Person[_]`:

```
val p: Person[_] = Student()
BoundUniversity(p)
```

fails compiling with:

```
inferred type arguments [_$1] do not conform to method apply's type parameter bounds [P <: Person[P]]
```

The same error happens for a method with a bound argument like:

```
def general[P <: Person[P]](p: P) = println(p)
```

so this is not specific to class constructors.

Two questions:

1. The type `Person` is defined with parameter bounds `Person[+T <: Person[T]]`, so that each instance of this type is insured to respect those bounds: `val p: Person[P]` implies that `P <: Person[P]`; or am I missing something? So how can I make this clear to the compiler so that it doesn't complain?
2. How/Can I define a case class with members with unbound type parameter like `case class University(p: Person[_])`?

Comment: Does `T` need to be covariant?

Comment: @dave in my particular case `T` needs to be covariant, but I think this does not change the problem: see the introductory example.

Comment: You could get somewhere using [abstract types](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/abstract-types.html), but then they become [pretty much invariant](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5359015/115478).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A type `X[_]` is hardly ever what you want. When you use `_` on a type, you are basically saying you don't care what that parameter is, because you'll never need to use it.

Anyway, this compiles. It may well bite you down the road, existential types being the tricky stuff that they are, but...

```
case class University(p: Person[t] forSome { type t <: Person[t] })
```

Comment: Nice existential type, thanks! This compiles, but cannot be instantiated with `val p: Person[_] = Student(); University(p)`. The type `Person[_]` I mentioned comes from a list: `List[Person[_]](Student(), Professor())`. Note that `List(Student(), Professor())` does not compile. I feel there is a pattern here but I cannot put the finger on it...

Comment: Actually this does not show errors in my Eclipse but does not compile with `scalac`. Type mismtach, found `Person[(some other)_1(in method equals)] where type (some other)_1(in method equals) <: schemdesc.hierarchy.eval.Person[_0]`, required `Person[_ <: schemdesc.hierarchy.eval.Person[_0]]`

Comment: @jullybobble The above line compiles -- I tested it. If you have a compilation problem, you are doing something different. And you cannot use `Person[_]` -- it won't work. You must use the existential type above if you want it to work.

Comment: I believe you test your code before posting it. I just re-tested it from scratch, I didn't manage to make it compile on my machine with scalac 2.9.1.final (with your `University` and my `Person` definitions). I'll try to dig in that further. Anyway, thanks for the existential types hint!